# Left click released not detected

Tags: unity, mouse

last Saturday I got a new wireless usb mouse (initially I had a wired USB mouse). I realised as soon as I started using it that it wouldn't detect that the left click had been released so it kept dragging the text/scroll bar. So I thought the mouse was faulty and sent it back. Today I plug in my old mouse which worked fine (before the new mouse was plugged in) but then it began having the exact same issue (it only began when the new one arrived and was plugged in).

[Here is a GIF of the issue](https://media.giphy.com/media/l49JVF9bWXHOtH7qw/giphy.gif)

```
mark@mark-Inspiron-3847:~ $ xinput --query-state 8
2 classes :
ButtonClass
    button[1]=up
    button[2]=up
    button[3]=up
    button[4]=up
    button[5]=up
    button[6]=up
    button[7]=up
    button[8]=up
    button[9]=up
    button[10]=up
    button[11]=up
    button[12]=up
    button[13]=up
    button[14]=up
    button[15]=up
    button[16]=up
ValuatorClass Mode=Relative Proximity=In
    valuator[0]=748
    valuator[1]=269
    valuator[2]=-1647
```